# ASP.NET MVC 3 Error and Exception Handling with 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, error-handling, elmah

What is the best way to log an exception and give the user the error code that was logged.  Along with this how are 404 errors handled.  I have seen many solutions for both but not together in a way that fits nicely with the mvc model.  Do you have an example too?  Also for 404's is there a way to get the 404 even if the user hasn't logged in to the app?

Is elmah something that should be used in production?
Is there a nuget package that people suggest using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use elmah, but make sure that access to the log viewer is controlled.

The package is Elmah.MVC, and make sure you read these:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx
http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/logging-on-mvc-part-1/

Comment: I saw that, i also so Elmah.Contrib.Mvc, have you used both and Elmah.MVC is a better architecture?

Comment: Do you know of any sites that use elmah in production?

Comment: @dre - How would I know what sites are using it?  It's not something you can really find out.

Comment: Thought someone might know, since people publish their technology stacks all the time.